# stopPropagation function reading not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, stoppropagation

I have a page with a lot of e.stopPropagation so what I decided I would do was to create a function. here is code

```
function stopProp(name) {
 if($(e.target).hasClass(name)) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   }
 }
```

Though each time in console it does not seem to work at all and says stopProp is undefined.

Here is the actual JS I am trying to turn into a function

```
$('#chatting').on('click','.chatheader',function(e){
     if($(e.target).hasClass('setting')) {
         e.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
});
```

Anyone can help me to figure out why this is not working and how I should go about this? I figured it would be fairly easy just to change to a function so I can easily write `stopProp('setting');`though that is not the case here.

Comment: please post you complete javascript code

Answer (score 1):

The handler of the `click` event should return with one single argument which will be the event. So you should have a function that returns an event, for example like this :

```
$('#chatting').on('click','.chatheader',stopProp('setting'));

function stopProp(name) {
  return function(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass(name)) {
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please see my comment to the other answer? As I want to know how to write the function of the .on() to do what I need to do for that specified element

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `event` object to the `stopProp` method.

```
function stopProp(e) {
    if($(e.target).hasClass(e.data.className)) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
}
```

Then

```
$('#chatting').on('click', '.chatheader', {className: 'setting'}, stopProp);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dg5x8/)

Comment: Ok so this looks very strange, sorry. I'd like to do something within the on click like so.

`$('#chatting').on('click','.chatheader',function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});`
So how would I do it like you said?
`$('#chatting').on('click', '.chatheader', {className: 'setting'}, stopProp,function(){
 $(this).fadeOut();
});`?

Comment: Use `$('#chatting').on('click', '.chatheader', {className: 'setting'}, stopProp).on('click', function(){ $(this).fadeOut(); });`